# Is it possible to define a Sonarqube portfolio with multiple criteria?

Tags: sonarqube

For our reporting purposes, I've created a few portfolios in Sonarqube. They are configured to associated projects by regular expression. However, we have now deprecated a number of projects, and would like to remove those from the portfolio, but keep for historical purposes. Is it possible to add a secondary configuration criterion to say exclude those with a "DEPRECATED" tag? We are running Sonarqube enterprise 8.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Received a response from support: It is not possible.